# Tempalte File won't update in Browser

Tags: javascript, webserver, smarty

im trying to change some behavior of a webpage. The page is built using SMARTY so the file that won't update is a .tpl file. Containing mostly JavaScript. The whole thing is weird because on my local drive (IDE) the file is the way i want it to be, it is the correct version on the server when i check it with SFTP.

BUT if i open the page with a browser, even a newly installed one, the code inside that page is the old version.

Now i can't send any error because there obviously is none.
So im lookin at a problem i can't fix or even begin to untangle.

I tried following things:

- Restarting apache2
- Deleting the file and uploading the correct version (here i might add the site broke when i deleted it and tried to view it)

This has been bugging me for a long time so it seems time couldn't fix it either.

I hope somebody has any idea to why this is happening!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clear (delete all cache files) smarty cache!
More details about cache dir: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.set.compile.dir.tpl

Comment: So i did delete all cached files and the newly generated file shows the correct version of code. YET the browser still doesn't use the correct version. (Yes i tried clearing browser cache)

Comment: ctrl+r, ctrl_f5 doesn't help?